# Unable to split std::array container into 2 sub-part

Tags: c++, function, c++11, pass-by-reference, stdarray

I have `std::array` container of `6` size and have to pass first `3` element of `std::array` container in one function by reference and Next 3 element in another function by reference. But I am not able to do it.

I converted `std::array<flaot,6> myarray` container into *c-style* array and passed `func1(myarray)` and `func2(myarray+3)` and again converted *c-style* array to c++ array container of `6` size.

For example:-

```
std:array<float,6> myarray={1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Now I want to pass the first three-element in first function and next three-element in another function by reference.

Comment: Please read [ask] and maybe [mcve].  Show us what you tried, explain how it fails including the errors, explain exactly where you are stuck.  If there are no errors but the output is wrong, then learn to use your debugger and/or how to add logging output.

Comment: have you tried `func1(&myarray[0])` and `func2(&marray[3])` ?

Answer (score 3):

> `std:array myarray={1,2,3,4,5,6};` Now I want to pass the first three elements in the first function and next
>   three-element in another function by reference.

Use the [`std::array::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array#Member_types) s instead.

Pass the non-const qualified iterators of `std::array` as the parameters of both functions and change the underlying element, which should be the easiest what you can.
That means,

```
func1(myarray.begin(), myarray.begin() + 3);  // first function
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

func2(myarray.begin() + 3, myarray.end);      // second function
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can do it because, `std::array::iterator` s are *[legacy random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)*.

Following is an example code. **([See online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zQJ5IRtM48HM5CCW))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using Iter = std::array<int, 6>::iterator;

void func1(Iter first, const Iter second)
{
    while (first != second)  // do something in the range
    {
        *first = *first + 1; // increment the element by one
        ++first;
    }
}

// same for the func2
void func2(Iter first, const Iter second)
{
    while (first != second) { /*do something in the range */ }
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 6> myarray{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 };

    std::cout << "Before calling the func1: ";
    for (const int ele : myarray)  std::cout << ele << " ";

    // pass the iterator range of first three elements
    func1(myarray.begin(), myarray.begin() + 3);  
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "After the func1 call: ";
    for (const int ele : myarray)  std::cout << ele << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Before calling the func1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 
After the func1 call: 2 3 4 4 5 6
```